# Register-PsRepository : The property 'Name' cannot be found on this object

Tags: powershell, powershellget

I'm getting below error when trying to run Register-PsRepository

I have tried:

- re-installing WMF 5, PowerShellGet and PackageManagement modules
- updating said modules
- debugging PowerShellGet module I can see that PsBoundParameters does pass the Name value to Register-PackageSource command.
- Register-PackageSource does work correctly when I run it manually.

Any Ideas?

```
PS C:\> Register-PSRepository -Name MyRepo -SourceLocation  https://MyRepo.com/api/Myrepo   -Credential $c
PackageManagement\Register-PackageSource : The property 'Name' cannot be 
found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
At C:\Program  Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.6.0\PSModule.psm1:4631 char:17
```

Comment: `Register-PackageSource does work correctly when I run it manually.` Why don't you use that instead?

Comment: Because some functions that are independent from me need psrepository registered, not only PackageSource

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check PSRepository configuration xml file:

> %localappdata%\Microsoft\windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\PSRepositories.xml

It's possible that file is corrupt and that could lead to an error you are getting.

Comment: Yes, Thank You Lukas! 
This file was corrupted, I have re-created the file  - everything works like a charm !

Comment: You, saved my day, that was the problem indeed!
In my case my code was running through DSC which is running under system account and the `PSRepository.xml` will be located under `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PowerShellGet\PSRepositories.xml`

Comment: Received a similar exception message (referencing `'Values'` instead of `'Name'` property in the message posted in the original question).

Removal of this file resolved, with no manual recreate needed.